# java failed to write bmp image in unix

Tags: java, unix, javax.imageio

error trying to write to bmp monochrome file in unix

i am using java to create and save a monochrome bitmap in unix but when i try to save it using:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "Microsoft Windows BMP", new File(resImagePath))
```

save a full black file and throw an IOException:

http://i57.tinypic.com/2re6pv5.png

java verion is 1.4.2

Supported format is shown in the picture

file has been created but fully black or fully white

full code:

```
final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1016, 648, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0,324,1016,648);

g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawString("Text Here", 100, 100);

gnu.javax.imageio.bmp.BMPImageWriterSpi bmp_writer = new gnu.javax.imageio.bmp.BMPImageWriterSpi();
bmp_writer.getWriterInstance();
registry.registerServiceProvider(bmp_writer);

if (ImageIO.write(image, "Microsoft Windows BMP", new File(resImagePath)))
    System.out.println("ok");
else {
    String names[] = ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        System.out.println("writer " + names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you dispose of the Graphics context before you write the image. There should be no need to instantiate a writer like this, as the implementation may change between platforms, you should be asking the ImageIO for registered implementations

Comment: I've tested your code, and after correcting for the portions that wouldn't compile and ensuring that the whole image is filled, not just part of it, it worked fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Use `bmp` instead of `Microsoft Windows BMP`

```
ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File(resImagePath));
```

In of itself, `ImageIO` does not modify the image data (beyond the requirements of the format), to generate a mono-chrome image, you will need to convert the image data yourself, for example...

[image: Monochrome]

```
try {
    BufferedImage master = ImageIO.read(new File("source image"));

    BufferedImage blackWhite = new BufferedImage(master.getWidth(), master.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    Graphics2D g2d = blackWhite.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(master, 0, 0, this);
    g2d.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(blackWhite, "bmp", new File("Test.bmp"));
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code produces the following output...

[image: Monochrome]

**Updated**

There's more going on in your code then meets the eye, for example, this works...

```
    final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 199, 199);
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    g.drawString("Text Here", 0, fm.getAscent());

    g.dispose();

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", new File("test.bmp"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestTextImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

[image: BMP]

But in your code, you are doing...

```
g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0,324,1016,648);
```

Which is only filling a portion of your (`1016x648`) image...

But then you do...

```
image_graphic.setColor(Color.black);
image_graphic.drawString("Text Here", 100, 100);
```

I have no idea what `image_graphic` refers to...

There should never be any reason to instantiate a `ImageWriter` directly, that's the whole point of `ImageIO`

Comment: bmp not supported, i use ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames() and it says i should to use "Microsoft Windows BMP"

Comment: You could also try BMP instead of bmp, not at PC to test

Comment: you're right but it was a mistake in text, i edited my question.and i'm using Unix S.C.O open server 5.0.7 and not windows,in windows there was no problem, but in unix ...

Answer (score 0):

some of problem solved.

i edit BMPImageWriter.java fileand method write().

commented last line that close stream

```
//out.close();
```

and done,but the system still print a *fully black* image when i use **TYPE_BYTE_BINARY**

```
final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1016, 648, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
```

if i use **TYPE_INT_RGB** or any colored format it will save correct,i am comming angry :((

Comment: What does the original image look like?

Comment: it's a new image created in code and add 4 lines of text to it

Comment: Have you tried saving the image out in a different, color format to test it?

Comment: Okay, considering posting the image generation code as well